# Accessing and Modifying UIImage Item at Another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am using Swift 2.0 and created controller like this:

```
class NewFortuneController: ViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var cupPicture1: UIImageView!
.....
```

How can i access and delete image of cupPicture1 when i am at different controller ?

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation please. How do you get to the other controller?? How is NewFortuneController back on screen?

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the NewFortuneController to do this.

You can do this in `prepareForSegue` if you are using segues and it's the destination controller you want to change

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "some identifier" {
        if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? NewFortuneController {
                controller.cupPicture1.image = UIImage(named:"image")
        }
    }
}
```

if it's the source controller that has the image you will have to set a reference back to the source controller, in the destination controller.

like:

```
AnotherController: UIViewController {
    weak var sourceController: NewFortuneController?

    func setImageForSourceController() {
        sourceController?.image = UIImage(named:"image")
    }
}
```

Then on `viewWillAppear` in NewFortuneController set the imageViewOutlet's image

```
class NewFortuneController: ViewController {
    var image:UIImage?
    IBOutlet weak var cupPicture1: UIImageView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        cupPicture1.image = image
    }
}
```